# Prove there is only one subgroup of order $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose I have a group $G$ of order $|G|=pq, q < p$ where $p,q$ are primes. Also, suppose that $a$ has order $p$, then prove that for any $b\not \in \langle a \rangle$, the order of $b$ is not $p$.

I know there is a way to do it with Sylow's theorems, but since we didn't cover Sylow theorems, I was hoping for another approach perhaps?

Comment: $b\not \in\langle a \rangle\Rightarrow o(a) \nmid o(b)$. So $p\nmid o(b) $

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Why??

Comment: I don't see why $b \not \in <a> \Rightarrow o(a)|o(b)$ right away?

Comment: The claim is false if you only demand $q\le p$. Just consider $G=(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, $q<p$ (strict). My example is $|G|=35=5\times 7$. It holds in this case.

Comment: If $b \not\in \langle a \rangle$ and $o(b)=p$, then $\langle b \rangle \cap \langle a \rangle = \{1\}$, so $|\langle b\rangle\langle a \rangle| \ge p^2 > |G|$, contradiction.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks! That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @DerekHolt, Also we can say  $b \not\in \langle a \rangle$ and $o(b)=p$ or $o(b)=pq$.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I don't understand your comment. What does "we can say" mean? We are assuming that $b \not\in \langle a \rangle$, and we are trying to prove that $o(b) \ne p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Sorry. I assume that $p|o(b)$. So $p\mid o(b)\mid pq$. It is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer.

If $b \not\in \langle a \rangle$ and $o(b)=p$, then $\langle b \rangle \cap \langle a \rangle = \{1\}$, and so $|\langle b \rangle\langle a \rangle|=p^2 > |G|$, contradiction.

Since you are looking for an elementary proof, I will justify the claim that $|\langle b \rangle\langle a \rangle|=p^2$. If not, then there exist $i,j,k,l \in [0 .. p-1]$ with $(i,j) \ne (k,l)$ and $a^ib^j = a^kb^l$, but then $a^{i-k} = b^{l-j}$ is a nontrivial element of $\langle b \rangle \cap \langle a \rangle$.

There is a general result that, for finite subgroups $A$ and $B$ of a group $G$, we have $|AB| = |A||B|/|A \cap B|$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $q$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, then any subgroup $H$ of index $q$ is normal.$^1$

Now in the given problem, what can you say about the image of $b$ in $G/\langle a\rangle$?

---

$^1$ Namely, $G$ acts by left multiplication on the set $X=\{\,gH\mid g\in G\,\}$ of the $q$ cosets, which gives us a homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to S_q$. Clearly, $\ker\phi\subseteq H$.
Note that $H$ leaves the point $H\in X$ fixed, hence is in fact mapped by $\phi$ into $S_{q-1}$. As $|S_{q-1}|$ is co-prime to $|G|$, we must have $H\subseteq \ker\phi$.

Comment: But surely you need to justify your claim that the subgroup of index $q$ is normal.

Comment: @DerekHolt This ought to have been shown shortly after the introduction of normal subgroups, typically as an afterthought to the beginner's exercise about the case of index $2$. With the Sylow theorems not covered but having been heard of, my guess was this was known ...